Ошибка при загрузке ServerManager, WindowsServer2019
При запуске получаю ошибку

Нашел инструкцию по исправлению, но дальше 4 шага продвинутся не могу, так как файл serverList пустой:

get-process ServerManager | stop-process –force
$file = get-item "$env:\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\ServerManager\ServerList.xml"
copy-item –path $file –destination $file-backup –force
$newserver = @($xml.ServerList.ServerInfo)[0].clone()
$newserver.name = “servername.domain.com”
$newserver.lastUpdateTime = “0001-01-01T00:00:00”
$newserver.status = “2”
$xml.ServerList.AppendChild($newserver)
$xml.Save($file.FullName)

